# WKWebView shows white bar until window moved/resized

Tags: macos, swiftui, webkit

I'm trying to show a WKWebView in SwiftUI on MacOS. When the app initially loads, the WKWebView has a large, white bar at the top. Moving or resizing the window causes this to immediately disappear and display correctly. Interestingly, the blue border around the view does not exhibit the bad behavior.

My guess is that I'm missing some action in updateNSView.

I'm on MacOS 11.1 Big Sur, Xcode 12.2, Intel. Another thing to note is that I need to enable the "Outgoing Connections" entitlement in the App Sandbox to get WKWebView to render anything at all, even tho the content is provided locally from a string.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

@main
struct ProblemWKWebViewApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SwiftUIWebView()
                .border(Color.blue, width: 2)
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIWebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    public typealias NSViewType = WKWebView
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.loadHTMLString("<body style=\"background-color: red;\"><h1>Hello World!</h1></body>", baseURL: nil)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

[image: Demonstrating the behavior]

Comment: Where do you specify the window size?

Comment: Also, where do you specify the web view size?

Comment: This looks like a bug, submit feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I suppose that it is a bug. However I managed to fix it with adding `ignoresSafeArea()`:

```swift
@main
struct ProblemWKWebViewApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SwiftUIWebView()
                .border(Color.blue, width: 2)
                // Shows weird black bar on top without this on macOS
                .ignoresSafeArea() 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, thank you, but there is a typo, it should be `ignoresSafeArea`.